# MYSQL C# get days left query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Hello Everyone I am trying to get end_date which is in the format of 2014-01-01

I want to use my subtraction method(which works) with my query of whats in end_date so I can make an if method to see if their subscribtion has payed but I do not know how to make a query  read end_date and compare it to date now

here is my code currently:

```
string myConnection = "server=****;user=****;database=***;port=3306;password=***;";
                MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
                MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT end_date FROM username = '" + this.username_txt.Text + "'", myConn);
                MySqlDataReader myReader;
                myConn.Open();
                DateTime endDate = get end_date from query here???;
                var DaysLeft = (endDate.Date - now.Date).Days;
                MessageBox.Show(""+ DaysLeft);
```

Comment: How do you put end_date in the DB?  If the DB generates it you would want the DB to do the subtraction.  Would be more efficient too...

Comment: It generates it by PHP when a purchase pays a query is initiated to add payed date and end_date and sure how would I go about doing that?and if you can do it for me I will be willing to pay skype: legendfinalhero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should get you started:

```
string myConnection = "server=****;user=****;database=***;port=3306;password=***;";
MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand(); 
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(), your_date)
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(), end_date) FROM TABLE WHERE username = '" + this.username_txt.Text + "'";
myConn.Open();
MessageBox.Show(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Change `TABLE` to the name of your table.  Other than that, I think it should just work.

Comment: Amazing thankyou so much Vijay, had to edit code a bit but none the less made it simple and easy you're awesome :)!

Comment: Ha, thanks... Don't forget to upvote my answer too.  Also, don't offer to pay people, you'll get ripped off... Just ask your question and always post code (as you did), it helps us help you...

Comment: alright thanks Vijay, one more thing tho before you go I made an if method with the object I created but it can't be an int so I'm not sure how I would do this
            int daysLeft = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            MessageBox.Show("Days Left: " + cmd.ExecuteScalar());
           if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 30)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("expired");
            }
        } 
says cannot implicitly convert type 'object to 'int

Comment: Hey, that's a different question, SO frowns on answering multiple questions with a single post.  Ask it in another question and post a link to the question here... I'll post you some more code... :)

Comment: Thanks bro, sorry I'm new and sure